# First letter of indexed span not selectable

Tags: html, tabindex

I have the following three spans:

```html
<span tabindex="-1">You can select the first letter of this span just fine.</span>
<span tabindex="-1">You cannot select the first letter of this span.</span>
<span tabindex="-1">You cannot select the first letter of this span, either.</span>
```

Run the snippet above. As the spans say, the first one lets you select its first letter (the "Y"), but the second and third one do not. Try it out - it may take a couple of times to get the cursor position right - but if you put your cursor roughly on top of the first letter of the first span, and then click and move your cursor to the right while holding the click in order to select some text, it will let you select the "Y". But if you try the same thing on the second and third span, it won't work.

I have isolated it to the tabindex. When I remove that, the selection works fine. Unfortunately, I need to keep the tabindex for my purposes.

It is reproducible in Chrome (latest version as of today 78.0.3904.108) but not in Safari (13.0.3).

Weird, isn't it? A Chrome bug, perhaps?

Comment: That is weird. For what it's worth, they are selectable if made into block-level elements, or by placing a line break after each span.

Comment: yeah, it's a curious bug related to inline display. Workaround to keep them on one line is to float the spans and make them block elements. The bug is the same with inline-block. Funny one.

Comment: Firefox 71.0 also works fine. Seems like a Chrome-specific bug.